# Disable History Command in Linux

Tags: linux

History command in Linux shows all recent commands run the server. Is there anyway to disable\to not show the commands run from one particular user account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

History is generally controlled by/part of the shell. The following assumes you are using `bash`, if that's not the case edit your question to include what shell you are using.

The file that it stores the history in is named in the `HISTFILE` variable. If you try:

```
echo $HISTFILE
```

You can see where it is being stored. For most it will be `~/.bash_history`. If you want to shut it off you can just remove the variable that says where to save the history:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

To make sure that it happens for the user on every shell startup, you can add the `unset` line to the user's `.bashrc` file.

You can also shut off the built-in history function with:

```
set +o history
```

Most of this is from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-bash-shell-history-linux/).